# hide a range of color from colorbar

Tags: matlab, colorbar

I have a map that contains values from 0 to 1 but also NaN contents.
I manage to defined a contour like map with the following code in MATLAB:

```
imagesc(map)
contourcmap('jet',[-0.3 0 0.3 0.6])
myMap = [[1 1 1]; ...
         [1 0 0]; ... 
         [0 1 0]; ... 
         [0 0 1]];
colormap(myMap);
cbar = colorbar
```

what I get is a map like this:[image: enter image description` here]

however I'd like to show only red,green and blue on the colorbar and get rid of the white range (i.e., [-0.3,0)) but don't want to change the color scale on the main map. is this possible in matlab?

Comment: The `repmat`s seem redundant.

Comment: you're right I forgot to correct that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`colorbar`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colorbar.html) is an [axes object](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes.html) and as such you can modify its [properties](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes_props.html), including the color limits. This is done through the `'YLim'` property, like this:

```
colorbar('YLim', [0 0.6]);
```

Or you can modify this at any time using the object handle:

```
cbar = colorbar;
set(cbar, 'YLim', [0 0.6]);
```

Comment: Actually when I use `hcont = contourcmap('jet',[-0.2:0.2:0.6],'colorbar','on','Location', 'horizontal'` and `set(hcont,'YLim',[0 0.6])` it does not work. do you know the reason?

Comment: Because then `hcont` is a handle to the `contourcmap` object, rather than the `colorbar` object. If you want to modify the colorbar's properties you'll have to get a separate handle for it through `h = colorbar;`.

Comment: yes but when I use `colorbar` the values on the ytick are not at the exact position that I want, little shifted. With `contourcmap` handel I used a different scale  like `set(hcont,'XLim',[1.5 9.5]))` and it works but don't know exactly why is that.

Comment: You can choose tick positions too through axes properties (`'YAxisLocation'`). Take a look at the link in the answer.